# how to change default font in android studio xml file

Tags: android

my app (android studio xml file) have a default font and I want to change it for a button it seems not be working even tho

I tried using fontfamily, typeface.

Comment: Do you have the font file "otf" in the android resources directory of type font?
it is the android:fontFamily attribute